# How to parse XML on NodeJS

Tags: xml

I have a XML in this URL: https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=science%5bjournal%5d+AND+breast+cancer+AND+2008%5bpdat%5d

I want to get all ID in "IdList". How to ?
I try with node2xml but without success..

An Idea ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below. It will give you the Ids and from there you can process it as you like.

```
    const xml2js = require('xml2js').parseString;
    const requestPromise = require('request-promise');

    const link = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=science%5bjournal%5d+AND+breast+cancer+AND+2008%5bpdat%5d';

    requestPromise.post(link, (error, response, body) => {
         if(error){
              console.log(error);
           return error;
         }
    }).then( (body) => {
         xml2js(body, (err, result) => {
             console.log(result.eSearchResult.IdList);
             return result;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many xml parser libraries.

You can try [xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parser)